# Losing 1 day when using get request Client Response javax

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am losing one day when get my data from backend to UI using the Client Response API call to get data. I know it is a timezone issue but failed to understand which timezone to set what.

Should I set timezone to UTC or my local time in Montreal and HOW. I am not sure how setting the timezone will affect other parts of the project which are working correctly.

This is my model class

```
public TradePurchaseOrderCopy getTradePOCopyByPoId(int id) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        Response response = client.target(URI.contextPathUI + "/api/tradePoCopy/id/" + id).request().get();
        TradePurchaseOrderCopy tradePOCopy = response.readEntity(new GenericType<TradePurchaseOrderCopy>() {
        });
        System.out.println(tradePOCopy.getDate()); // getting date 2019-09-25, which must be 2019-09-26

        return tradePOCopy;
    }
```

This is my controller class

```
@GetMapping("/tradePoCopy/id/{id}")
    private TradePurchaseOrderCopy getTradePOCopyByPoId(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        TradePurchaseOrderCopy t = tradeCopyService.getTradePOCopyByPoId(id);
        System.out.println("dateL : "+t.getDate()); // getting date 2019-09-26, which is correct
        return tradeCopyService.getTradePOCopyByPoId(id);
    }
```

EDIT 1;
TradePurchaseOrderCopy Class:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.List;

public class TradePurchaseOrderCopy {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer poId;

    private Company vendor;

    private Double paidAmount;

    private Double depositTransfer;

    private boolean vendorInclude;

    private boolean isBrand;

    private String documentCountry;

    private Company pickup;

    private Time pickupAppt;

    private Date dropDate;

    private Time dropAppt;

    private Date createDate;

    private Integer createEmployee;

    private Date switchDate;

    private Time switchAppt;

    private Date requestDate;

    private Date deliverDate;

    private Time deliverAppt;

    private Date otherDate;

    private Date puDate;

    private String vendorOrderNumber;

    private String b13;

    private String bic;

    private Integer po2;

    private Integer termId;

    private ShipTerm shipTerm;

    private ShipTo shipPlace;

    private Date paymentDueDate;

    private Integer carrierId;

    private Integer puId;

    private String sealNumber;

    private String exportNumber;

    private String containerNumber;

    private Double containerTare;

    private Integer deliverId;

    private boolean deliverInclude;

    private Integer deliverId2;

    private boolean deliver2Include;

    private Integer switchId;

    private boolean switchInclude;

    private boolean prepaid;

    private Currency currency;

    private boolean seaway;

    private boolean tis;

    private boolean active;

    private Date date;

    private Integer editEmployee;

    private Date ts;

// respective getters and setters
}
```

Comment: can you show the `TradePurchaseOrderCopy` class

Comment: sure please check the Edit 1. Haven't included getter/setters as they will overcrowd it

Comment: Is the date retrieved from DataBase (since you have java.sql.Date) in TradePurchaseOrderCopy ? If so the timeZone of your Database and the PC time zone where you call the endpoint could cause this. Can you share the timeZone of DBServer and the machine timeZone where you call the endpoint!?

Comment: My PC is using Eastern time zone(UTC-05:00) and SELECT @@global.time_zone; says SYSTEM so both are same.